# properties of positive definite matrices 3 2 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $M+M^T$ is positive definite, then $M$ is invertible?

Since the matrix $M+M^T$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the matrix $M + M^T$ is invertible, but I don't know if I can conclude the same about M.

Comment: If $Mx = 0$ then what would $x^T(M+M^T) x$ be?

Comment: If $Mx = 0$, then $x^T(M+M^T)x = x^TMx+x^TM^Tx=x^T(Mx)+(Mx)^Tx=0$, right?

Comment: Yes. So if $M$ is singular then $M+M^T$ is not positive definite.

Comment: You are welcome!